# Cocos2d Font Extensions Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ipod-touch

Good afternoon, sports!

I have a fast doubt.
I'm using COCOS2D and i need to know if i can use other extension type of font other than ".fnt".
Because i used a few and didn't have any luck.

I'm using this piece of code to make a "credits" scene:

```
CCBitmapFontAtlas* l_026  = [CCBitmapFontAtlas bitmapFontAtlasWithString:@"Look for our apps in the AppStore"   fntFile:@"fission.fnt"];
```

If it isn't which can i use?
And it is do you know any font converter to change "normal fonts" to ".fnt"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best font program in my opinion is:  [Glyph Designer](http://glyphdesigner.71squared.com/).  It is inexpensive and very easy to make great looking fonts.

I use CCLabelBMFont but I'm pretty sure it is basically the same thing.

Comment: Glyph Designer looks great! but $29.99 is still not cheap to me :P

Comment: Just a question though: does it support auto-creation of Retina/non-Retina versions? If it does than I'm going to buy it myself. I tried emailing the author before but he/they aren't responding.

Comment: I'm not sure. I know Cocos2D can auto select standard and HD versions. I also know for sure that exporting a font at one size and then exporting it again at a different size generally takes all of 10 seconds.

Comment: Yes the exporting doesn't take long, but I need to modify all the parameters for outline, shadow etc before exporting for different sizes otherwise the proportion is out, right? It'd be easier if the tool can do all that automatically.

Comment: Sometimes you need to change that stuff and sometimes you don't. Often I don't need to change it at all. If it doesn't have it I'm sure they would put it in for you. Thing is though, if shadows and whatever else need to be tweaked for different sizes, you would end up with the same problem. Better to do it manually I think. Does not take very long...unless your app needs a few thousand fonts or something, which I doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some cash to spend you can use Glyph Designer as suggested by Aaron. But you can also use a free Java tool named **[Hiero](http://n4te.com/hiero/hiero.jnlp)**. You might have to do some tweaking to get the result you want though.

The tool will output 2 files: one `.png` and another `.fnt`. Add these files into your Xcode project and use it using simple lines like below:

```
CCLabelBMFont *some_label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:@"Your Text" fntFile:@"fontfile.fnt"];
```

Do note though that the size of the font from each pair of fnt/png files is fixed, so you have to create multiple pairs if you want to have different font sizes. Also, you need separate pair for Retina and non-Retina display modes.

Comment: Often you can scale the font a bit without anything strange happening. Depends on the situation. Scaling up is not really recommended though.